# Отсортировать значения по возрастанию в массиве объектов класса

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка, объекты

**Задание:** Создайте класс с именем train, содержащую поля: название пункта назначения, номер поезда, время отправления.Ввести данные в массив из пяти элементов типа train, упорядочить элементы по номерам поездов.
Добавить возможность вывода информации о поезде, номер которого введен пользователем.
Добавить возможность сортировки массив по пункту назначения,
причем поезда с одинаковыми пунктами назначения должны быть упорядочены по времени отправления.

**Суть проблемы:** не получается отсортировать по времени поезда с одинаковыми пунктами назначения.

**КОД:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class train {

public:

    char destination[100];
    int TrainNumber;
    int hours;
    int minutes;

    bool CheckingHours() {
        if (hours < 0 || hours > 23) {
            cout << "Некорректный ввод!";
            return false;
        }
    }
    bool CheckingMinutes() {
        if (minutes < 0 || minutes > 59) {
            cout << "Некорректный ввод!";
            return false;
        }
    }
    void PrintTime() {
        if (hours <= 9) {
            if (minutes <= 9)
                cout << 0 << hours << ":" << 0 << minutes;
            else
                cout << 0 << hours << ":" << minutes;
        }
        else if (minutes <= 9)
            cout << hours << ":" << 0 << minutes;
        else
            cout << hours << ":" << minutes;
    }
};

int main() {
    setlocale(0, "");

    train trains[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << "Введите номер " << i + 1 << "-го поезда: ";
        cin >> trains[i].TrainNumber;
        cout << "Введите пункт назначения " << i + 1 << "-го поезда: ";
        cin >> trains[i].destination;
        cout << "Введите время отправления " << i + 1 << "-го поезда: ";
        cout << "\nЧасы: ";
        cin >> trains[i].hours;
        if (trains[i].CheckingkHours() == 0) return 0;
        cout << "Минуты: ";
        cin >> trains[i].minutes;
        if (trains[i].CheckingMinutes() == 0) return 0;
        cout << endl;
    }

    int info;
    cout << "\nВведите номер поезда: ";
    cin >> info;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (trains[i].TrainNumber == info) {
            cout << "\n\nПоезд №" << trains[i].TrainNumber;
            cout << "\nПункт назначения: " << trains[i].destination;
            cout << "\nВремя отправления поезда: ";
            trains[i].PrintTime();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (trains[i].destination[0] < trains[j].destination[0]) {
                swap(trains[i], trains[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (trains[i].destination == trains[j].destination && i != j) {
                if (trains[i].hours > trains[j].hours) {
                    swap(trains[i], trains[j]);
                }
                else if (trains[i].hours == trains[j].hours) {
                    if (trains[j].minutes > trains[j + 1].minutes && j < 5) {
                        swap(trains[j], trains[j + 1]);
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "\n\nОтсортированы по пункту назначения: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << "\nПоезд №" << trains[i].TrainNumber;
        cout << "\nПункт назначения: " << trains[i].destination;
        cout << "\nВремя отправления поезда: ";
        trains[i].PrintTime();
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста если мой ответ вам помог, то выберите его как "Правильный ответ" нажав на галочу слева от ответа :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример кода с комментариями:

```
//Алгоритм сортировки пузырьком
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4 - i; j++) {
        //Сравниваем 2 строки
        //strcmp - возвращает 1 если левая строка > правой строки
        //возвращает 0 если левая строка == правой строки
        //возвращает -1 если левая < правой строки
        int res = strcmp(trains[j].destination, trains[j + 1].destination);
        //Если левая строка > правой то свапаем
        if (res == 1)
            swap(trains[j], trains[j + 1]);
        //если пункты назначения равны
        else if (res == 0) {
            //Проверяем уже по времени
            //Если час отправления левого поезда > правого, то свапаем
            if (trains[j].hours > trains[j + 1].hours)
                swap(trains[j], trains[j + 1]);
            else if(trains[j].hours == trains[j + 1].hours) {
                //Аналогично часам
                if (trains[j].minutes > trains[j + 1].minutes)
                    swap(trains[j], trains[j + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Поподробней про алгоритм сортировки пузырьком можете почитать [тут](https://code-live.ru/solutions/cpp/3/)

Пусть входная строка будет:

```
1 Moscow 10 15 2 Paris 11 10 3 Moscow 9 30 4 Madrid 10 30 5 Berlin 12 10
```

Тогда результат программы будет следующим:
[image: Результаты]